# Is there an example of an algebraic surface with a (-2)-curve and...

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Recently I am curious about the minimal model program on varieties of log canonical Calabi-Yau type over complex numbers. That is, a log canonical pair $(X,B)$ such that $K_X+B \sim_Q 0$. Given such a normal variety $X$, one may ask if we can run an MMP on an arbitrary pseudo-effective divisor on $X$ (but this process does not necessarily terminate).

To construct a counter example, I like to ask if there exists such an algebraic surface $S$ with the following properties:

1) there is a (-2)-curve $C$ (i.e. $C^2$=-2)

2) $K_S+C \sim_Q 0$

If such a surface exists, then it seems hard to run an MMP on the divisor $C$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $S$ be the blowup of $\mathbf{P}^2$ at eleven smooth points on a cubic curve $C'$. Then, we have an effective curve
$$C \in \lvert 3\ell - E_1 - E_2 - \cdots - E_{10} - E_{11}\rvert$$
corresponding to the strict transform of the cubic $C'$, where we denote $\ell$ by the strict transform of a line in $\mathbf{P}^2$ and $E_i$ the exceptional divisors. Then, $C$ is a $(-2)$-curve:
$$C^2 = \left(3\ell - \sum E_i\right)^2 = 9 - 11 = -2,$$
but we have
$$K_S = -3\ell + \sum E_i,$$
hence
$$K_S + C \sim 0$$
as required.